# Как стилизовать отдельное слово

Tags: текст, стилизация

Например я получаю строку из хранилища ил БД, не суть.И вывожу на экран. Например так

```
String User = pref.getString("User","");
String textName = this.getResources().getString(R.string.text_name);
TextView.setText(textName + " " + User + " ?");
```

Как для **User** задать стили? Размер,цвет и тп?

Comment: Что такое TextView? О чём тут речь вообще? Что-то про андроид?

Comment: Да, что за язык, что за фреймворк? Нужно добавить теги.

Comment: Блин, сори. Забыл, что это не специальный ресурс))). Java